# jump to next trial after key press

Tags: python, events, key, break, psychopy

In my experiment, I have 10 trials, and at each trial, the participant has to press a key ("space") asap after seeing a change of colour in the animation. As feedback that confirms the key pressing, I'd like to move to the next trial (move to the next loop iteration) after the key was pressed. I tried to implement the idea in my code with `break` and `continue`, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in range(nTrials):

    # Start with fixation cross 
    fixation.draw()
    win.flip()
    core.wait(2)

    # Play the video for 200 frames 
    for Nframes in range(200):
        optic_flow_movie.draw()
        fixation.draw()
        win.flip()

    # Get Participants responses
    keys = psychopy.event.getKeys(keyList=["space"],timeStamped=clock)

    if (keys[0][0] == 'space') is True:
        break
    else:
        continue

# Take only the timestamps from the variable key and store it in the variable RTs  
RTs = [sublist[1:2] for sublist in keys]                     # This stores only the timestamps
RTs = [item for sublist in RTs for item in sublist]          # This converts from list of lists to a flat list
```

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the structure of your trial is, but if you want to monitor responses during the animation, then the call to `event.getKeys()` needs to be embedded within the drawing loop (i.e. within `for Nframes in range(200):`). That way, you are checking for a keypress on every screen refresh, so the animation can be halted in realtime.

At the moment, the code shows the entire animation and only then checks the keyboard (but just once per trial). Regardless of what happens there, the next trial will begin, as that is the last code in the main trial loop (i.e. `for i in range(nTrials):`.

Lastly, the `event` module is deprecated for keyboard responses. You should really shift to the newer `Keyboard` class for much better performance:

https://www.psychopy.org/api/hardware/keyboard.html

https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/3-ways-to-get-keyboard-input-which-is-best/11184/3

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used `keys = kb.getKeys(['space'], waitRelease=True)`, followed by `if 'space' in keys: break` within the drawing loop and it worked. However, I got the following warnings and I am not sure what they mean or whether it is affecting the timing `1.4501  WARNING  Import Error: No module named 'psychtoolbox'. Using event module for keyboard component.` and `2.5451  WARNING  PTB audio lib was requested but not loaded: psychtoolbox audio failed to import`

Comment: I guess you're not using the standalone app, but your own custom installation of PsychoPy? If so, it looks like you don't have the `psychtoolbox` library installed, which is necessary to use the new keyboard class. In this case, PsychoPy is falling back to use the older `event` module.

Comment: I downloaded the standalone app, but as I wanted to use Psychopy as an imported module in my code editor (Visual Studio), I installed psychology with `pip install`. Is there a solution to this problem, would it be possible to use Psychopy as an imported module without it falling back to use the older `event` module?

Comment: Yes, it just looks like you’re missing the `psychtoolbox` library. Can you try installing it individually with `pip install psychtoolbox`? Look here for some preparatory steps that might be necessary first: https://www.psychopy.org/download.html